Copy URL of current Wikipedia revision without resorting to the history page
Is someone aware of e.g. a browser or Mediawiki userscript that gives a link to the current revision (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Polemic&oldid=1223303279)?
I rely on it when making long-term references to Wikipedia.

All pages on Wikipedia have a link in the sidebar, "Permanent link" that does exactly what you are asking for.


By the way, how do you enable that content assessment label "A start-class article"?

In your preferences on the gadgets tab, you can activate "Display an assessment of an article's quality in its page header"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-gadgets

The API call https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Polemic&rvslots=*&rvprop=ids
will return a JSON like this:
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "pages": {
            "385549": {
                "pageid": 385549,
                "ns": 0,
                "title": "Polemic",
                "revisions": [
                    {
                        "revid": 1223303279,
                        "parentid": 1217661719
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

json.query.pages[ pageid ].revisions.revid will contain revision identifier. Prepend https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Polemic&oldid=.

Thanks! I will now make a bookmarklet.
